# How to draw planar representations of platonic graphs using named graphs of `tkz-berge`

Tags: tkz-berge

I want to draw planar representations of the 5 platonic graphs.  Package `tkz-berge` has commands to draw such graphs.  I managed to obtaint the planar representations of all but the dodecahedral (using different radii and/or forms).  Is it possible to obtain a planar representation of the dodecahedral using the standard command `\grDodecahedral`?  How?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grTetrahedral
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grOctahedral[RA=5,RB=1]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grCubicalGraph
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grIcosahedral[form=2,RA=8]
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grDodecahedral % failed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tkz-berge package offers 5 forms of a Dodecahedral.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}

form 1    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grDodecahedral[form=1] 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
form 2     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grDodecahedral[form=2] 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
form 3     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grDodecahedral[form=3] 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
form 4     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grDodecahedral[form=4] 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
form 5     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \grDodecahedral[form=5] 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image]

## Choose form=3 or form=2 for planar

Comment: @r-schumacher: Is this documented? Where? I did not find the different forms in [this file](http://altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/NamedGraphs.pdf).

Comment: I went to the tkz-berge documentation, and noted that on page 103 he discusses that there are four embeddings done.  Elsewhere in the manual he related the different embeddings to the key value `form`.  So then I just tried form 1+ and found there were 5 available in this package of the 10 in the Wolfram article referenced on page 103 of the `tkz-berge` documentation.